# NoSuchMethod error for ImageView.setColorFilter

Tags: java, android

So I have a ListView that color codes an icon based on the priority of each item in the list. For example, priority 1 workorders have a red workorder icon. Priority 2 = yellow, etc.

I use ImageView.setColorFilter(Color.whatever) to change the color of the icon and it works great on my Samsung Galaxy Tab and HTC Hero, however when I load the app onto an HTC Droid Eris, I get an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:android.widget.ImageView.setColorFilter
```

I have no idea why it works fine on everything else, but not this phone. Any ideas? I'm thinking perhaps it might be due to the Eris having Android 2.1 whereas the rest are 2.2 or higher. But I wouldn't think such a basic method was not included before 2.2!

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! This community always helps when I'm stumped and Google won't spit back any relevant results! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter%28int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29) and filter by API version, you'll see that this overload:

```
void setColorFilter(int color)
```

was introduced in API version 8, which is Android 2.2.

However, there are other overloads which were supported earlier:

```
void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf)
void setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)
```

Could you use one of those instead?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I actually just came across it myself as I got the email saying you had posted a response! Thanks for the quick feedback! It's awful trying to keep track of which version each thing was released at (currently this is the only method that prevents me from releasing the app for API level 7, so I may just have to change it)

Answer (score 1):

`setColorFilter(int color)` was introduced in API level 8 (Version 2.2).

There are two other versions of `setColorFilter` which exist since Version 1.0, maybe you could use those instead?

Comment: Thanks! I will be using the (int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode) method instead. I am accepting Jon Skeet's answer though simply because he posted quicker, but I definitely appreciated the help!